# Having a collision object. How to kill particles from a defined source?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I have two independent objects (P1, P2) with particle system on each of them. I have another object (C1) with collision and option kill particles enabled. Is there a way to configure C1 so that it only kills particles originating from P1, while sparing particles originating from P2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let particles **Die on Hit** by enabling this feature for one of your *P* object.
Collision object with *Kill Particles* option can do the same, but there is not a possibility to restrict it for a specific particle system - it works globally.

*Particle System Properties > Physics > Deflection > Die on Hit*

[image]

[image]

Or you can let collide particles with specific group of objects via **Collision Collection**.